# Non-self-intersecting paths on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,1\}$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, cv.complex-variables, differential-topology, fundamental-group

Let us make two small holes around points $0$ and $1$ on the complex plane and consider non-self-intersecting paths that start on the boundary of one hole and finish at the boundary of the another. It seems,
that all these paths are homotopic to the segment of the real line.

How to prove this? Is there any conceptual explanation of this fact?

Comment: Is there anything to be said about the nature of the holes or are these just tiny circular closed disks?

Comment: You have to specify the nature of the homotopy.

Comment: Just a guess but there's the winding number around each hole separately, which you can unwind by a homotopy?

Comment: The title seems in conflict with the details in the body of the question.

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "homotopic to"? If the meaning is all maps $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathrm{smalldisks}$ are homotopic, *relative to the endpoints*, to the "real segment between the disks", then it's clearly false in general (if e.g. $\gamma(0)$ is not real). In other words: how are the endpoints allowed to move during the homotopy?

Comment: There are (at least) **three** different notions of homotopy applicable in this situation, which lead to (two) different answers. It is your responsibility to state clearly which notion of homotopy you are using. Voting to close for now. The question is also more suitable for MathStackexchange, as I do not see a research aspect to this question.

Comment: @Misha, this question seems perfect for MO.

Comment: @Wlod AA Thanks!

Comment: Supposedly "This question needs details or clarity." == But I DID supply perfect details and clarity. It is sick, that my EDIT was simply rejected without eventually supplying anything in return. It is sick that once again mathematics loses to MO administration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a homotopy exists and in fact you can assume that it is an isotopy.  This is a "standard fact" in the theory of mapping class groups.  See Proposition 2.2 of the "Primer" by Farb and Margalit.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! It is a simple fact, indeed. My question was mostly about some kind of explanation of this fact. For example, this is not true for other surfaces, they have some non-trivial non-self-intersecting paths... Anyway, thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the two holes are two small disks. Then connect their boundaries by a cylinder (homeomorphic copy of  $[0,1]\times S^1$) lying out of the plane. Let us also add the complex $\infty$ to the space (meaning: let us start with the Riemann sphere in the place of complex plane). The resulting space is homeomorphic to the torus, so its fundamental group is $Z$, the integers. Any given closed path $p$ should belong to the homotopy class $n\in Z$ if and only if the total oriented number of passages of $p$ through the cylinder is $n$; I suppose this can be obvious from some particular way how the homotopy group can be calculated (but I am not strong at this presumably ?basic exercises). Your curve is to be completed to closed curve p_1 by one passage through the cylinder. The real segment is to be completed to a closed curve p_2 also by one passage through cylinder. So p_1 and p_2 are homotopic. It seems to me "obvious" that the homotopy does not do anything serious in the cylinder and can be modified to live in your complex domain (asside from trivial part that trivially transits between added parts of p_1 and p_2). I admit this "obvious" thing might require a substantial use of algebraic geometry or real analysis.

Now, the $\infty$ I added plays no role: The homotopy  intersect the complex plain in a bounded region, it never reaches $\infty$.

(If one of your 'holes' is two disks itself, say $B(0,1/9) \cup B(i,1/9)$, then the curve might be non-homotopic to the segment. E.g. if it passes around above B(i,1/9) or winds it.)

Comment: Replacing two points by two disks changes the question significantly. Also, the fundamental group of a torus is not  ℤ  but  ℤ$^2$.

Comment: Others may feel different but I don't see any positive contribution to solving the *Question*, not even a partial contribution.